# ASP.NET Core 3 - Logging with NLog does not log exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm using the ASP.NET Core logger along with NLog. When I log an error/critical with an exception, the message is logged but the exception doesn't.

```
try
{
    // my code throws an exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogError($"There was an error", ex);
    return null;
}
```

My NLog configuration looks like this:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="ApiLogger" fileName="Logs\api-${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate} - ${uppercase:${level}} - ${threadid} - ${logger} - ${message} ${exception:innerFormat=Message,StackTrace}" />
```

Whats logged in the file is `There was an error` without the actual exception and stacktrace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct syntax that you want for an ASP.NET Core logger is

```
ILogger.LogError(Exception exception, string message);
```

The code written is using the extension method

```
ILogger.LogError(string message, params object[] args);
```

This means you should try using this instead:

```
try
{
    // my code throws an exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogError(ex, "There was an error");
    return null;
}
```